# Why are some textures disappearing in the game engine?

Tags: texturing, game-engine

I have a mesh that I am texturing for the game engine and everything was fine until the last setups I've done; Some of my textures don't appear anymore. What strikes me is that the colors are correct so pictures are taken into consideration but not displayed correctly. 
[image: in viewport]

[image: in-game]

Is it a UV problem? Can't I use more than two UV layers on my object?

How do I include the blend file in this post?

Comment: you can use a service such as [blend exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload your blend.

Comment: Yes, currently Blender Game Engine has real problems with multiple UVs. Especially if you're using noeds(you don't seem to do though). However, UPBGE is coming along with some fixes, expect them to be there soon. Oh, and you can mark your answer as `answered` if it is your solution. That way you'll earn additional reputation;)

Answer (score 1):

So instead of using multiple UV layers for scaling the textures i used the 'size' option in the 'mapping' panel. It runs faster...